# What are the unusual weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2

TF2's recent update, the Gun Mettle update, says you can get Unusual weapons. But it doesn't clarify anything about what choices you have for Unusual weapons.

What are the unusual weapons I can get? Is it every gun in the game? Or is it just a set series of guns. Are there different effects?

Comment: Has that update actually been released yet?

Comment: @Studoku I'm at work but I think it's already out? Not sure, will have to go home and see update progress

Comment: I just tried playing. As far as I can tell it's going to be another hour or so.

Comment: Update hasn't hit and there are no indications as to when it will (only that it will be sometime today).

Comment: The question might be a bit pre-emptive, but I wouldn't vote for close now. After all, it's only a matter of time (propably a few hours) 'till it's on-topic again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The only weapons that can be Unusual are the weapon skins from the Powerhouse and Concealed Killer *case* collections.** No other weapons can be Unusual.

There is a higher chance, however, of the skin you uncrate being Strange, but an *extremely rare* chance of getting it both Strange and Unusual.

According to the wiki, the only four effects you can get on an Unusual skin are Isotope, Hot, Cool and Energy Orb.

[image: Isotope Unusual effect]
[image: Hot Unusual effect]
[image: Cool Unusual effect]
[image: Energy Orb Unusual effect]

Comment: As far as I know, the new weapons from the Invasion update can be unboxed in unusual quality.

Comment: @Powerlord Looking at the wiki, that doesn't seem to be the case. None of the weapons have 'Unusual' listed as an available quality.

Answer (score 2):

The update now allows certain cases to drop when completing contracts. The case drop system works VERY similar to Counter Strike: Global Offensive, you have a chance at obtaining a variety of new weapon skins. Skins that can come in 3 conditions, and have a rare chance at also coming with a stat trak(you'll have a little number on your gun showing your kills, it's basically a strangifier)

As for the UNUSUAL effects, these are the rarest of qualities. These modify your gun to have a particle effect applied to them, much like VALVE quality weapons. You have Isotope(a green hypnotic type of ring effect), COOL(Turns your gun ice/navy blue with some snow flakes falling and having a icy mist to it), HOT(which makes your gun RED HOT with a steam effect) and then Energy Orb(which makes your gun red and cloudy like the energy hole effects) - As of right now, none have been found, but my guess would be ANY weapon can have the effects on them. Much like UNUSUAL hats, there's a variety of effects for most hats, it wouldn't make sense to have them on stock only.

Answer (score 1):

Most of this is just guesses but using my prior knowledge of how these things work out and how this update looks, I'd say that

1) It's probably only stock weapons, like the skins
2) There are probably different effects, and I'm 95% sure that one of them is shown on the update page. On the picture of the pixelly-skinned rocket launcher close up with the statclocker thingy, the end of the gun is flaming, sparking, and smoking. I believe that will be one of the effects.